# Final consonants: ways of compensating for the lack of voicing in initial and final position.

Tags: consonants

this question (Final consonants: ways of compensating for the lack of voicing in initial and final position.) is part of my exam but I fully don´t understand what it means.

Please can someone tell me what ways of compensating there are?

Comment: You say you don't *fully* understand. Could you tell us what you do understand, please?